# Trigger on update should update other table sqlite3

Tags: database, sqlite, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_accept
        AFTER UPDATE OF toaddress ON tripletlist
        FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            UPDATE triplets
            SET accepted = accepted + 1
            WHERE senderip = inserted.senderip
            AND fromaddress = inserted.fromaddress
            AND toaddress = inserted.toaddress;
            DELETE FROM tripletlist WHERE toaddress != "";
        END;
```

Here I want to update triplets when triplist get updated but i am just updating to address and I want to update triplet list with (accepted) +1 and where will fromaddress and senderip while I am just updating to address.

Comment: Please provide a full description of the problem, input tables, current output, expected output and eventual errors you're getting.

Comment: I want to update table triplet when I update table tripletlist I will update toaddress in this table but in other table it should update accepted column by +1, Here I am just updating toaddress in this table but want to update with three columns as mentioned in where clause.

Comment: Here Delete is working fine I just want update query.

Comment: Use NEW instead of inserted

Comment: @forpas tried that too but does seem working.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html#description

Comment: Yeah but its not working I had used old new before after.

Comment: Check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=03b21b3068f56a669874eee00201af80

Comment: Yeah I know this is working but I got the culprit. The culprit is toaddress it is not allowing me get data from toaddress. Why I dont understand it is giving me issue. If I change the column name then also it is not working.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with sample data here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27?

Comment: Thank You So Much  @forpas the code was proper yours and mines both but the issue was the space because of which I faced this issue. I had updated 6 times then also it has been updating only twice can you tell instead for FOR EACH ROW it will better to use any other.

Comment: SQLite supports only FOR EACH ROW triggers

Comment: Thank You. I am not using this now and removed this.